# How to create a list with several entries

Tags: r, list, rep

I want to create a list with 1000 files including all just containing the value 20 (7 times).

For example

[1] 20 20 20 20 20 20 20

[2] 20 20 20 20 20 20 20

...

[1000] 20 20 20 20 20 20 20

```
result = list(rep(20,7))
```

This way I just create one list.

```
result = as.list(rep(20,1000))
```

And this way I create 1000 lists containing just one entry. 
I tried to implement two "rep" functions. For example

```
result = as.list(rep(rep(20,7), 1000))
```

But unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
x <- replicate(1000,rep(20,7),simplify = FALSE)
```